# Distribution of Number of Approvers

Tags: transaction, confirmation

Every transaction directly **references** two previous transactions. But I was wondering, does this also mean that every transaction will be **referenced by** exactly two transactions or will it be random? If it is random, what does the distribution look like?

Comment: They will have to be referenced by at least one transaction to give them a chance of being confirmed. Some transactions (e.g. milestones) will be approved by very many transactions), while others only have one. I don't have a full node handy so I'll wait for someone else who wants to write a script to evaluate this :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume every transaction directly **references exactly** `k` other transactions (`k = 2` in the case of IOTA). Now under uniform random tip selection, every transaction will **on average** be **referenced by** `k` other transactions (due to the stationarity property).

The histograms below provide a visual proof of this. I assumed a network delay of `h = 1` with `40k` transactions per simulation. For comparison purposes, I am including two examples for the issue-rate `λ` (10 and 20).

[image: Histogram for k=2]
[image: Histogram for k=3]
[image: Histogram for k=4]
[image: Histogram for k=5]